# Вопрос по поводу загрузки документов в vk.com

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api, post, вконтакте

Я хочу загрузить файл .zip в документы юзера в vk.com, в документации написано, что для этого нужно пройти 3 этапа:

1. Получить адрес сервера, что у меня получилось
2. На этом этапе
   нужно загрузить файл,  получить JSON-объект с полем file, которое используется на 3 этапе,вот на этом этапе у меня всегда приходит
   `{"error":"unknown error"}`
3. Сохранить файл

Подскажите, пожалуйста что я делаю не так,
`uploadUrl` - это путь к серверу vk.com, полученный на первом этапе.

```
func uploadFileToServer(_ uploadUrl: String, withFileUrl name: URL, onCompletion:@escaping (_ receivedFile: String?) -> Void) {
let url = URL(string:uploadUrl)
guard let urlExist = url else { return }
var urlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: urlExist, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
var dataZip: Data?
do {
dataZip = try Data.init(contentsOf: name)
} catch let error as NSError {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}

var _params: [String : Data] = Dictionary()
_params["file"] = dataZip
var body = Data()

let boundary = "---------------------------0983745982375409872438752038475287"

let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
urlRequest.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")

if let zipData = dataZip {

body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition: attachment; name="Document"; filename=".zip\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
body.append(zipData)
body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
}

body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

urlRequest.httpBody = body

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
[weak self](data, response, error) -> Void in
print(response)
if let data = data {
do {
if let returnData = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
print(returnData)
onCompletion(returnData)
}

} catch let error as NSError {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}

} else if let error = error {
print(error.localizedDescription)
}

}
task.resume()

}
```

Post-запрос выглядит так:

```
  ▿ url : Optional<URL>
    ▿ some : https://pu.vk.com/c816630/upload.php?act=add_doc&mid=100453791&aid=0&gid=0&type=0&hash=73a86d9f7e3c4f301cd6e270973b9402&rhash=feb4d83139ca61b46b2a0fefba55e1ce&api=1
  - cachePolicy : 1
  - timeoutInterval : 30.0
  - mainDocumentURL : nil
  - networkServiceType : __ObjC.NSURLRequest.NetworkServiceType
  - allowsCellularAccess : true
  ▿ httpMethod : Optional<String>
    - some : "POST"
  ▿ allHTTPHeaderFields : Optional<Dictionary<String, String>>
    ▿ some : 1 element
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - .0 : "Content-Type"
        - .1 : "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------0983745982375409872438752038475287"
  ▿ httpBody : Optional<Data>
    ▿ some : 207058 bytes
      - count : 207058
      ▿ pointer : 0x0000000121b29000
        - pointerValue : 4860317696
  - httpBodyStream : nil
  - httpShouldHandleCookies : true
  - httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Comment: Вы 3-й этап не забыли?

Comment: @0xdb до третьего этапа я не дохожу еще, так как мне нужно получить JSON-объект с полем file,

Comment: Зачем тогда его упоминать в вопросе? Поправте с учётом вашего комментария.

Comment: @0xdb , хорошо я попроавила, вы можете подсказать в чем пробема в данном случае?

Comment: Проверьте закрывающие  кавычки в body.append.

Comment: @0xdb, проверила, там все нормально

Comment: Посмотрите внимателеней, во 2-м 5-ь не экранированых кавычек.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо, оправила, но ошибка та же